# set QGraphicsScene dynamically in QGraphicsView with OpenGL Viewport

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have a problem, i'm developing a graphical program under Windows, there are few QGraphicsScene and one QGraphicsView that it is possible to change the Scenes in runtime with a lot of graphics items, the problem is when I use Qwidget viewport everything works but when I switch to OpenGL viewport when I change the scene the content of previous scene still appear on the QGraphicsView and the contents of new Scene appear too.

what is the problem ? is it the changing Scenes method best solution or should I change the method ?

here is the code to setup View

```
m_viewPort     = new QOpenGLWidget (this);

QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
format.setStencilBufferSize(8);
format.setSamples(4);

m_viewPort->setFormat(format);

ui->gV->setViewport(m_viewPort);

ui->gV->setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate);

//ui->gV->setCacheMode(QGraphicsView::CacheBackground);
ui->gV->setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing| QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing | QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform| QPainter::TextAntialiasing);
ui->gV->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
ui->gV->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy  (Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
ui->gV->setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView::NoAnchor);
ui->gV->setAutoFillBackground(false);
ui->gV->setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent, true);
ui->gV->setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground, true);

resize(boardBaseSize);
```

here is code to set the new scene to the view

```
void GlScreenBoard::setShowScene(QGraphicsScene *scene, QString programName)
 {
 scene->setSceneRect(boardSceneRectBase);

 ui->gV->setScene(scene);
 }
```

another problem is when I set Graphics view CacheMode to CacheBackground the OpenGL viewport disables !! and the painter in QGraphicsScene returns to Raster !